# Wordpress custom foreach loop with $authors troughs an error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Default `wp_list_authors` will return authors list in the following format:
`<a href="#">AuthorName</a> (PostCount)`

I want to display authors list with post count in the following format:
`<a href="#">AuthorName (PostCount)</a>`

The following `custom foreach loop` with authors troughs an error (`Invalid argument supplied`).
 **Any suggestiosn what I am doing wrong?**

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'post_count', 
        'order'         => 'DESC', 
        'optioncount'   => true, 
        'exclude_admin' => false, 
        'show_fullname' => true,
        'hide_empty'    => false,
        'echo'          => false,
        'style'         => none,
        'html'          => false );

    $author = wp_list_authors($args);
      foreach($author as $author->ID) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_the_author_link( $author->name ).'">'.get_the_author().' ('.count_user_posts($author->ID).')</a></li> ';
    }

?>
```

Comment: The reason you're getting that error is because the function isn't returning an array, it's returning just a comma-separated string of the authors' full names. See my answer below in order to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually redoing what the [`wp_list_authors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors) function can do already. You can remove that whole `foreach` and just use the following code to achieve what you want:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'optioncount'   => true,
    'exclude_admin' => false,
    'show_fullname' => true,
    'hide_empty'    => false
);

$authors = wp_list_authors( $args );
```

Use this exactly where you want the list to be displayed, since it'll be shown there.

Comment: What if I want to show author list in '<select>'. In order to do that I need to wrap each author in '<option>'. Can you please guide me here.